# How to keep a value taken from a rule in a variable and reuse it in the ANTLR grammar?

Tags: java, antlr4

I declared String variables in my grammar, **vAttributeName** and **vClassName**, and I assign them with the text values of the tokens : **className** and **attributeName**. When I use one of the variables that should normally contain a value in an error alternative so in another rule, it returns a null in the message ... Why do not my variables keep the values? How can I fix that?

```
grammar TestExpression;

@parser::members {
            String vAttributeName;
            String vClassName;
            }

/* SYNTAX RULES */
textInput               : classifierContext ;
classifierContext       : 'context' c=className attributeContext {vClassName = $c.text;};
attributeContext        : '::' a=attributeName ':' dataType initDefinition {vAttributeName = $a.text;};
initDefinition          : 'init' ':' initExpression ;

initExpression          : boolExpression
                        | decimalExpression
                        | dateTimeExpression
                        | .+? {notifyErrorListeners("Corriger - "l'attribut "+vAttributeName+" de l'entité "+vClassName+" ne correspond pas");}
```

I'm trying to parse an expression who describe a class with an attribute that has a false value.

And the message i expected was : "Corriger - l'attribut **seat** de l'entité **Car** ne correspond pas".

But the actual message was : "Corriger - l'attribut **null** de l'entité **null** ne correspond pas".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a rule like `a: b c {action};` and an input that matches that rule, events will happen in the following order:

1. The rule `b` is applied and its action is executed if it has one.
2. The rule `c` is applied and its action is executed if it has one.
3. The action `action` is executed and is able to access the results of the `b` and `c` rules (including anything set by their actions, which is why it's important that those have run first).

If you have `a: b {action} c;` instead, then the action will be executed after `b`, but before `c` (and will consequently be unable to access `c`'s result).

So for your code that means that the action of `initExpression` is run before those of `classifierContext` and `attributeContext` and that's why the variables aren't set. You can fix the problem by moving the action, so that it happens directly after the needed part (i.e. `className`/`attributeName`) has been parsed.

You could also get rid of the variables altogether and instead get the desired information by getting it from your grandparent contexts.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right for the order of the actions. Thank you @sepp2k.

I'm new with ANTLR4, so what do you mean that i could get the desired information from the grandparent contexts ? How i do that in an action ?

Comment: @talohsa You can use `$ctx` to get the context object of the current node, you can then access `parent` on that to get the parent node. So inside an action of `initExpression`, `$ctx` will give you the `InitExpressionContext` object, `$ctx.parent` will give you the `InitDefinitionContext` and `$ctx.parent.parent` would be `AttributeContextContext`. However the static type will be `ParseRuleContext`, so you'll need to cast to be able to access methods from `AttributeContextContext`. So to get the attribute name, you could use `((AttributeContextContext)$ctx.parent.parent).a.getText()`.

Comment: Note that this assumes a specific tree structure and will break if you change the grammar in a way that changes the structure of the tree or if you invoke the `initExpression` rule from multiple places in the grammar (where `attributeContext` isn't (always) the parent's parent).

Comment: Okay, I understand now. It's working now. You helped me a lot, thank you @sepp2k.